# Outlook for Mac 2016 & Gmail

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, gmail

Has anyone gotten Outlook on Mac to behave properly when using with Gmail? 
Because of the Archiving feature, All Mail is synced with Outlook, and that's great.

But, whenever I search for a mail, or check out a conversation, all e-mails appear twice, once in their folder (label), once in All Mail.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. If you have two-factor auth enabled on your Gmail account, the password will need to be the app password you create.

[image]

Comment: I have the same set up. Outlook connects to GMail without an issue. The thing is that when searching it displays two copies of each e-mail, one from "All Mail" and one from the folder (label) where it's placed.